# Is there a way to auto-combine rows with nearly identical values but update the cells that are unique?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I integrated an auto-refreshing log sheet on Google that records Zoom attendance for every event action triggered. Since I want to specify the "Join Time" when a meeting participant enters the room and the "Left Time" every time they disconnect, what the log sheet does is record these two values into two different rows.

This is how it looks like:
[Nearly Identical Rows Each with One (1) Unique Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLI26.jpg)

Is there a way to auto-combine these rows while updating the cells with their respective unique values (Join Time and Left Time)? Thanks!

I tried using this formula, but it doesn't work

> =UNIQUE(
> ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(
> BYROW('Reference-Sheet'!$C$4:C4,
> LAMBDA(name,JOIN("|",name,JOIN(", ",FILTER('Reference-Sheet'!$C$4,'Reference-Sheet'!$D$4 'Reference-Sheet'!$E$4:$E$4,'Reference-Sheet'!$F$4:$F$4,'Reference-Sheet'!$G$4:$G$4,'Reference-Sheet'!H$4:$H$4, 'Reference-Sheet'!$I$4:$I$4,'Reference-Sheet'!$J$4:$J$4,'Reference-Sheet'!$K$4:$K$4,'Reference-Sheet'!$L$4:$L$4,'Reference-Sheet'!$M$4:$M$4,= name)))),
> "|")
> )))

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this, as long as every single log record is paired together and contains a single join time and left time.

```
=HSTACK(FILTER(A:H,ISERR(H:H)=FALSE),FILTER(I:I,ISERR(I:I)=FALSE))
```

It simply filters out the rows where H is an error, then adds column I with the non non error values (corresponding time).